# WebApi URL parsing - How can I get the inline parameters of the URL?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, httprequest, parameter-passing

I have a WebApi URL as below:

```
https://baseaddress/controlapi/api/parameters/Gateway
```

The parameters controller has `API` method as follows, the Gateway is the parameter value for the service parameter:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string service)
{
}
```

`GetQueryNameValuePairs()` to get the query string key value pairs from the `HttpRequest`. Similarly is there a way to get the inline parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's about routing. In WebApi 2 you can define a route to match an URI.

You could try something like this:

The «parameters» in the pattern needs to be specified in your method with the same name to match the content in the request.

```
[Route("controlapi/api/parameters/{parameters}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string parameters)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
    response.Content = new StringContent(parameters, Encoding.Unicode);
    return response;
}
```

You can see how it works correctly.

[image: Requesting a specific URL through PostMan app with the.]

[image: Getting the parameters value (Gateway) in Visual Studio.]

Comment: The question is about how to get the parameters values from the http request. Sorry if I was not clear in the question. What I am looking for is the way to get the parameters from the Uri like https://baseaddress/controlapi/api/parameters/Gateway

Answer (score 0):

If you are inside a route of a WebApi Core controller, you can always access the full query string as follows:

```
string? query = this.Request.QueryString.Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**